# How to open and edit an existing file in Python?

Tags: python, file, save

I've been working for a while now on a variety of different programs to practice my Python, the most notable being my choose-your-own-adventure game, which is well over 1000 lines so far.  More recently, I have been trying to edit files from within Python, and I can't seem to figure it out.  For instance, if I set a variable to a user input like so:
`input1 = raw_input("What is your favorite food?")` Then, let's say I want to save this text to a .txt file that already exists, like `food.txt`.  How would I do that?

Comment: "I have been trying to edit files from within Python ... " - so can you show what code you have, and why it does not work.

Comment: Do you want to append the new content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) maybe will be help,

the code such as

```
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "a") # safer than w mode
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Comment: Again, opening existing files in `'w'` mode is not a good idea, you'll lose the content of your file.

Comment: so, should be "a" mode ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what OP wants to do exactly (the question is not super clear), but 'a' mode is safer than 'w' because at least you won't lose the existing contents.

Comment: I tried this, but when I checked the pass.txt file it was still empty.

Comment: @Drew Nolan, be careful about the file name in the sample code, it should be changed accordingly.... to pass.txt

Answer (score 2):

The `open()` built-in Python method ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#)) uses normally two arguments: the **file path** and the **mode**. You have three principal modes (the most used): `r`, `w` and `a`.

- `r` stands for *read* and will make the `open("/path/to/myFile.txt", 'r')` to open an existing file and to only be able to read it (not editing), with `myFile.readlines()` or other methods you can find in [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).
- `w` stands for *write* and will not only erase everything the file had (if it existed), but let you write new stuff on it through `myFile.write("stuff I want to write")`.
- `a` stands for *append* and will add content to an existing file without erasing what could have been written on it. This is the argument you should use when adding lines to non empty files.

You must not forget to close the file once you have finished working with it with `myFile.close()` because it is only at that point where all the changes, updates, writings, are done.

An small snippet for adding a line:

```
f = open("/path/to/myFile.txt", 'a')
f.write("This line will be appended at the end")
f.close()
```

If the file contents were something like

```
"Stuff
Stuff which was created long ago"
```

Then the file, after the code, looks like

```
"Stuff
Stuff which was created long ago
This line will be appended at the end"
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a file named food.txt

```
f = open('food.txt', 'w')
```

To write as a new line:

```
f.write("hello world in the new file\n")
```

remove the \n if you want it on the same line.

to read it you can do for example

```
print(f.read())
```

If you wish to append:

```
with open('food.txt', "a") as f:
    f.write("appended text")
```

Comment: Opening an existing file (that presumably OP wants to keep the contents of) in write mode is a bad idea, it wipes the existing content of the file.

Comment: @Marius maybe you shouldn't be so hasty with the down vote next time. opening it with the argument 'a' is allowing me to modify the text file. Maybe you would like to explain how this works if my understanding is incorrect?
[Example for you](http://i.snag.gy/9hsN2.jpg)
-
I have shown that appending it can be done with 'a', and creating it new/opening new file can be done with 'w'. I don't see why you would downvote me.

Comment: Could you remove the downvote please? As you clearly hadn't read the whole answer.

Comment: Yes, 'a' mode is OK, but 'w' mode is not. OP says in their question that they already have a file called food.txt, if they started trying out your code they could have lost the contents of their file.

Comment: Not trying to lecture you about 'a' vs 'w' mode, my point is that if OP isn't as familiar with this stuff as you they could try to run your first line and lose their file, you should warn when giving potentially 'dangerous' code samples to people still learning to code.

Comment: He would have understood if he read the whole answer. And I'm pretty sure this question has been asked hundreds of times on stack overflow. And again, OP should know that good coding practices include keeping a copy of all original files and then to begin experimenting. OP never said he wanted to append to a file or not, he just said he had an existing file. So there is nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: You all need to calm down.  As you guessed, I'm not as familiar with this stuff as you guys, but I appreciate the time you all take to give me tips.  Don't waste even more time fighting over something this stupid.

Comment: I am calm, just educating Marius on how wrong he is. Btw Drew, I hope you understand the distinction between using 'w' and 'a'. I hoped you picked that up from my answer. Also, next time I would recommend doing a quick google or stackoverflow search as this question has been asked many times.
May I refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python

Comment: I found all the other tutorials, and none of it worked. That's why I asked, and this isn't working for me either and I have no idea why.  But I do understand the difference between "w" and "a" mode - thanks!

Comment: How is this not working for you? What are you specifically doing? I'd like to help you solve this.

Comment: Well, at first I copied everything with different file names and such, but that didn't work so I literally copied and pasted this code, with a new file that was called "food.txt" and did all that and such.  Copied and pasted.  Still didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell me what the exact problem is you have to solve? I will try to code it in python and give it to you.

Comment: Nothing specifically, just have the user input something and record said thing in a file.

Comment: Try copying and pasting this code into an editor and then running it (through cmd or linux terminal I assume (if you need help with that ask)) http://ideone.com/N3j8h6
It gives an error on Ideone because I am not allowed to modify text files on the website.

Comment: @user2780354 Didn't work.  I'm doing it on a mac, though.  Could that have something to do with it?  An app called CodeRunner.

Comment: I have no idea why it isn't working. here is me running it and the output. I'm not very hardware-savvy so I wouldn't know about the mac.
Does it run without errors?
Do you have python installed?
Here is mine http://i.snag.gy/9hsN2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit ambiguous, but if you are looking for a way to store values for later use and easy retrieval; you might want to check [ConfigParser](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples). :)

Answer (score 0):

I find beautiful module for this task - [in_place](https://pypi.org/project/in-place/), example for Python 3:

```
import in_place

with in_place.InPlace('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace('test', 'testZ')
        file.write(line)
```